# Log.INFO vs. Log.DEBUG

Tags: logging

I am developing a large commercial program and keep confusing myself between what kind of information i want to log with Log.INFO and Log.DEBUG.

Are there any standards or canonical Python Enhancement Proposal / Java standard conventions / rules defined for other languages on what each type of log message contains?

Answer (score 192, accepted):

I usually try to use it like this:

- **DEBUG**: Information interesting for **Developers**, when trying to debug a
  problem.
- **INFO**: Information interesting for **Support staff** trying to figure out the context of a given error
- **WARN** to **FATAL**: **Problems** and **Errors** depending on the level of damage.

Comment: can INFO be enabled always in production, will it have any performance impacts?

Comment: It depends.. (I like that answer) The factors you need to take into account are:
1. Amount of info log lines
2. Logging setup (where do your logging lines end up?)
3. Available processing and io power on the concerned systems.

Comment: And be aware that the more noise, the more difficult it is to spot problems.

From http://plumberjack.blogspot.be/2010/09/python-logging-functionality-facts-vs.html:

> In common with the Unix philosophy, software should not be excessively verbose except when it needs to be, or is asked to be.

(why can't I get this quoted?)

Answer (score 61):

> • **Debug**: fine-grained statements concerning program state, typically
>   used for debugging;
>
> • **Info**: informational statements concerning program state,
>   representing program events or behavior  tracking;
>
> • **Warn**: statements that describe potentially harmful events or states
>   in the program;
>
> • **Error**: statements that describe non-fatal errors in the application;
>   this level is used quite often for logging handled exceptions;
>
> • **Fatal**: statements representing the most severe of error conditions,
>   assumedly resulting in program termination.

Found on http://www.beefycode.com/post/Log4Net-Tutorial-pt-1-Getting-Started.aspx

Comment: Should errors triggered by user input be treated as warnings or errors? (I.E. Incorrect username or password)

Comment: @Stevoisiak based on his answer I guess it should be treated as an info.

Answer (score 14):

Also remember that all `info()`, `error()`, and `debug()` logging calls provide internal documentation within any application.

Comment: I think it's a good point. E.g. `log.info("parse the widget text; ignore contents of 'foo'")` serves as useful documentation when reading the code, even though it is also a log statement.